# How to only display first three lines of output in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to create a script that will check when the most recent update was done to a Windows machine. Then, if the most recent update was greater than 90 days old, send an email notification to itadmin email and run an update (I dont have the email portion added yet but that's just a copy pasta). The issue that I am having is that I want to show only the three most recent updates in get-WUHistory, and have th evariable Update time catch those. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Also I should add that I have very little Powershell experience, I only started with it about two weeks ago so it could be a silly question.

---

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Force
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Force 

$Version = (Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('ReleaseID')
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)
$UpdateTime = Get-WUHistory | Format-List -Property Date

Write-Output $Version

If($UpdateTime -lt $Date){
    ########################
}

If($version -lt 1909){
    Write-Host("This computer is not up to date") -ForegroundColor Red
    Get-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -Download  
}
else {
    Write-Host("This computer is up to date" ) -foregroundcolor green
    Write-Host("Checking for patches") -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -category "Security Updates" -Severity Critical,Important,Moderate 
}

#Restart-Computer -force
```

Comment: To limit a command's output to the first 3 objects, pipe to `Select-Object -First 3`.

Comment: As an aside: In PowerShell, functions are invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo(arg1, arg2)`; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a function sees as a _single_ argument.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects.

Comment: other pb your're hardcoded the version "1909" i think you have to search and find a way to connect to microsoft lastest update version throw api or webservices to get this values